# Login System with Ajax and PHP - how can I improve security and control user permissions?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, authentication

For the first time in a few years, I am trying to realize a small project in my free time. Its nothing big and only will run on a local computer. But since I want to learn something new I want to focus on dynamic content.

The user has to be logged in to access the landing page.
And the shown content depends on user permissions.

In the past, I just mixed PHP with HTML and gained some poor codes (in my opinion) because I had PHP code in the body Tag for example.

My code on every page and subpage always started with

```
 <?php

      session_start();
      //check permissions and if the user is logged in
      //redirect to login.php if not

      //create navigation bar based on user permission or include another .php file

      ?>
```

And sometimes I even echoed HTML code.

For the first time, I try to use "modern" technologies to completely separate the backend from the frontend and keep the code .html code clean from any PHP snippets inside.
I try to use basic HTML/CSS/JS for the frontend and using whatever (right now PHP) for the backend.

Right now, my "check" if the user has the permission to see the content is done with ajax and a PHP script.

I have an event handler for the load event of Pages (or sections) and pass the value to a PHP script, here is the example for my start.html

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var verusr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  verusr.open('GET', '/inc/php/login.php');

  verusr.onload = function() {
      if (verusr.status === 200) {
        if(verusr.responseText !== 'true') {
          window.location = 'login.htm';
        }
      }
      else {
        alert('Request failed.');
      }
    };
    verusr.send();

  }
```

My login.php does all that verification stuff, creates a session and echo's true or false.

**Is this a safe way to protect a site?**

I guess not because the user is able to see the content if he disables JavaScript, right?

So the workaround here would be to build the content of the page dynamically.

Right now my navigation looks like:

```
  <nav class="main">
                <ul>
            <li><a href="#1">Test1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Test2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Test3</a></li>
            <li class="right"><a href="/inc/php/logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

This is what anybody would see with disabled JavaScript if he visits my website. That wouldn't be a big problem, but it isn't nice either.

A possible workaround here would be to build the page more dynamically, right?

For example, I could return a JSON Array instead of true/false which contains everything which is accessible and call a function "createNav" which loops through every array element and creating a list element?

Would this be a safe approach? Since there is no content before JS is running you can not disable it to see anything.

But despite the security question, is it fast enough?

I would plan to continue this approach. If someone clicks Link #1 it would trigger an AJAX Post (passing "1" to a Script) and the Script would decide what Data to show, but the JS decides how to build the content.

Or would it be enough to return a "link" to a .html file which can be included then? And this file has an onload event itself to prevent it from direct access?

Because formerly I protected my pages and subpages (which have been included) with a PHP snippet like above, but protecting it with AJAX interacting with this snippet is difficult for me because you you don't have to necessarily run the script or you could maybe manipulate the return of the script (or change the script itself).

But when there aren't any data on the Client (despite a StyleSheet) in the first moment, it should help.

I hope I could explain what I meant and I am looking forward to your opinions.

Comment: Welcome to SO. your question seems to be an xy problem. In my opinion you should split it in to smaller parts. First part - Creating (or using some already given) login system separatly(not dependant on any data, besides the data it needs to identify a user). Second part - displaying dynamic data. Each of these parts is quite hard alone, and can be done several different ways. Also my recomendation would be to leave AJAX alone for the time being. Almost everything you want can be done without JS at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop all your business logic in the backend using PHP and create API for each activity/content of frontend. These API will only accept data and send the response only in JSON format.

Now, All you have to do is always use anchor tags or `<input type="button">` only to send data or redirect to other page and write javascript functions to handle JSON response/data to display content.

I think this will be a neat and clean approach to separate the backend from the frontend and keep the .html code clean from any PHP snippets inside.

Though you will have to take all major decision (business logic, permission check, permission-based navigation, permission-based page blocks to show/hide and its content) at backend API by returning some flags or JSON of multiple flags/data and it will tell frontend (javascript functions) what to show and what not and what to render in which way. You also need to make it very strict while building arrays of data/flags and returning JSON through API which will actually build you website using frontend (HTML/JS/CSS).

So much theory... I know but the architectural approach for an application is hard to explain with an example. But for further explanation/examples, I completely agree with @Eugene Anisiutkin (break it).